Novel about the protagonist trying to survive/escape a human farm
I know virtually nothing about this book/novel beyond vague descriptions.
It's about the protagonist trying to survive/escape a human farm. I'm not sure if the farm was run by zombies or aliens. The humans are selected to reproduce and the protagonist is not selected with whom he wants.
From what I've been told, it's classified as a "disturbing" novel.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Unfortunately I didn't read it, it was a recommendation that a random person once gave me about 3 years ago, but all the details he gave me are the ones I wrote in the post
